# Redirect all pages to subdomain while keeping the content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I want to redirect all my pages and video content to my sub domain (where I have my CDN)

currently I have link in a videogame, with people who generate traffic and I have a lot of link already in the game that I cant change since it will take forever, so I want redirect all people that will click on the link to my sub domain, where I have my CDN setup

`https://exemple.com/folder/contents/video.mp4 TO https://cdn.exemple.com/folder/contents/video.mp4`

I already try few rewrite command with htaccess but I get the error `TOO_MANY_REDIRECT` and I don't know what to do

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried ?

Comment: I try multiple rewrite rules on htaccess, I don't remember all of them since I been looking into a lot of different one but at the end, all of them was working, it was redirect my content to my sub domain while keeping the path but I had a error saying too many redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.mp4)$ https://cdn.exemple.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Put this at the top of your `/root/.htaccess` before other rules  and make sure to Clear your browser cache before testing this new redirect.

Comment: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

I still get the same error

Comment: @RootBeer what URL is causing this error?

Comment: When I set the rewrite rules, the redirection of `https://exemple.com` to `https://cdn.exemple.com` make the "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" , but when I don't have any rewrite rules, my cdn sub domain work fine

Comment: @RootBeer The rule is working fine for me and it  should not cause this infinite redirect error.  Are there any other rules that can conflict with this one?

Comment: No, only this one

Comment: @RootBeer This rule does not redirect your hompage. Only the URLs ending with `.mp4` get redirected to your cdn domain. If `http://example.com/` redirects to `cdn.example.com` then there is something else creating this redirection.

Comment: I'm using Plesk currently, I have no other rules in the .htaccess

Comment: @RootBeer Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, to be more simple, if you want to can talk on twitter, might be more easy to communicate since I cannot message you on this website

Comment: @RootBeer sure we can!